# Why would a statistician or mathematician want to find the ratio between two maximum likelihood in a likelihood-ratio test?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Why would a statistician or mathematician want to find the ratio between two maximum likelihood function in a likelihood-ratio test?

I know maximum likelihood is the maximum of the probability distribution, but what is likelihood-ratio test using for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the Neyman-Pearson lemma.

Comment: Please explain what is Neyman-Pearson Lemma and an example please?

Comment: It is a standard theorem discussed in any statistics textbook that discusses hypothesis testing. You can just search for it and find numerous descriptions on the internet.